# Why methods returns object of interface type?

Tags: java, interface, inner-classes

I am trying to understand the way, how interface works. After doing some research, I found that interfaces are used to specify what a class must do.

I implemented a method(`first()`)in outer class which will return element of  `Position<E>` instance, but the main point where I get confused is, `first()` uses a method `getNext()` from Node class which returns `Node<E>` object, so why I am able to return `Position<E>` object instead of `Node<E>` and I can even return `Node<E>` object from `first()` method.

```
private static class Node<E> implements Position<E> {// Inner Class
    private E element;
    Node<E> previous;
    Node<E> next;

    Node(E element, Node<E> previous, Node<E> next) {
        this.element = element;
        this.previous = previous;
        this.next = next;
    }

    @Override
    public E getElement() throws IllegalStateException {
        if (next == null)
            throw new IllegalStateException("Position no longer valid");
        return element;
    }

    private Node<E> getNext() {
        return next;
    }

}
```

Outer class method

```
@Override
public Position<E> first() {
    return header.getNext();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since `Node<E>` implements `Position<E>`, each instance of `Node<E>` is also an instance of `Position<E>` (or, to be exact, an instance of a class that implements `Position<E>`).

Therefore you can return an instance of `Node<E>` in a method whose return type is `Position<E>`.

Answer (score 0):

> why I am able to return Position object instead of Node

Because, `Node` implements `Position` and that implies `Node` is a type of `Position`. So, `Position` can hold any class instance, who implemented it. In your case, it is `Node` class,  referring to `getNext` method, which returns `Node` type object

```
private Node<E> getNext() {
    return next;
}
```